# ASP.NET MVC 2 connected drop-down lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know, how can i make 2 connected dropdowns (not cascade). 
The point:

I have a list:

```
List<SelectListItem> harmingFactorsList = new List<SelectListItem>();
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
    foreach (var item in db.CatalogHarmingFactors)
    {
        harmingFactorsList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.Nr, Text = item.Description});
    }
}
```

The 1st dropdown have to show `Nr` field and the 2nd corresponding `Description` field. So, if user will change 1st dropdown, the value in the 2nd dropdown must be changed automatically and vice versa. The goal is to make them both have the same item selected, ever.

I have no idea how to make it works. Can it be made with Html helper or do i have to use Javascript and switch them `onchange`?

Comment: This is going to have to be a Javascript solution.  Html helper's are useless for this because they are just used to display information, not listen for events (such as onchange).

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this? You could simply set the label property to show both values? Which would be more semantically correct as you are indeed showing only a single item you just happen to want to show two properies?

Comment: @Milney Yes the OP could set the label property to show both values, but what the OP is asking is that if a user decides to change the value in the dropdown, then the 2nd one needs to change.. and vice versa.. at least that's what I got from the question

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I understand that - I am simply asking WHY they want to do that? I would be confused if I saw two dropdowns relating to the one item... Having one dropdown that uses both values as the label eg. "Nr - Description" would be a lot clearer and semantically correct in my option so just pointing that out incase OP hasn't considered that (easier) option

Comment: @Milney ahh okay I think I see what you're saying. Good question.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Are you suggesting to concatenate `Nr` and `Description`? I dont think it will look pretty (`Description` field stores long strings ).

Comment: Okay, if it is a long string, you think that it would look pretty in a dropdown box?  I think there needs to be an alternate solution.

Comment: I need to allow user to chose value by 'Nr' OR by 'Description', like in the example below - chose somebody by his name or surname.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Dropdown box? What do you mean?

Comment: @rainbowShiningUnicorn I meant dropdownlist.  So does my example below give you what you need/are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **think** that this is what you're trying to achieve via Javascript.  You can edit this how you please, but it gets the job done.

Simple Example:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="FirstName">
  <option>-- Select --</option>
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="Abraham">Abraham</option>
  <option value="George">George</option>
</select>

<select id="LastName">
  <option>-- Select --</option>
  <option value="Doe">Doe</option>
  <option value="Lincoln">Lincoln</option>
  <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
</select>
```

---

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$("#FirstName").change(function(){
    if(this.value === "John"){
    $("#LastName").val("Doe")
  };
    if(this.value === "Abraham"){
    $("#LastName").val("Lincoln")
  };
    if(this.value === "George"){
    $("#LastName").val("Washington")
  };
});

$("#LastName").change(function(){
    if(this.value === "Doe"){
    $("#FirstName").val("John")
  };
    if(this.value === "Lincoln"){
    $("#FirstName").val("Abraham")
  };
    if(this.value === "Washington"){
    $("#FirstName").val("George")
  };
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabo5mdx/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i thing this helpful..

**pure java script**

```
    <select id="drp1">
    <option value="val1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Text 3</option>
    <option value="val4">Text 4</option>
</select>

<select id="drp2">
    <option value="val1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Text 3</option>
    <option value="val4">Text 4</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var drp1 = document.getElementById("drp1");
    var drp2 = document.getElementById("drp2");
    drp1.onchange = function () {
        fixValues(drp1, drp2);
    };
    drp2.onchange = function () {
        fixValues(drp2, drp1);
    }

    var fixValues = function (drpFrom, drpTo) {
        var val = drpFrom.options[drpFrom.selectedIndex].value;
        for (i = 0; i < drpTo.options.length; i++) {
            if (val == drpTo.options[i].value) {
                drpTo.selectedIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**jqyery**

```
    <select id="drp3">
    <option value="val1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Text 3</option>
    <option value="val4">Text 4</option>
</select>

<select id="drp4">
    <option value="val1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Text 3</option>
    <option value="val4">Text 4</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#drp3").change(function () {
            $("#drp4").val($(this).val());
        })

        $("#drp4").change(function () {
            $("#drp3").val($(this).val());
        })
    });

</script>
```